# My phone is missing from my devices tab

Tags: google-play-store, google-location-history

My phone (which I have been using for more than a year) never appeared in my devices tab in google play store or when I check my location history. In the track my phone area it appears normally but in play store (desktop website) it does not appear.

If it matters, I own an Xperia C4

Comment: Click on the gear icon, Settings, is you device shown there?  You may need to check under Visibility to "Show in menus".

Comment: @RMarkwald no it is not. Even though the tablet I got a lot later is there